# Deleting white space after using offset path in Illustrator cc 2020

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I am currently creating a logo in illustrator cc 2020 and have used offset path to create space between overlapping lines.

[image]

If I put any kind of background under this then the white offset path shows. Is there a way of deleting these whilst keeping the gaps?

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Use knockout groups

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the Shape Builder Tool.
While holding down Option key (alt on PC) drag through the area you want to delete and it will remove it.
Adobe's Tutorial:
[Shape Builder Tool](https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/creating-shapes-shape-builder-tool.html)

Comment: Perfect, thank you :)

Comment: You are very welcome!